# SQL code, can it be shorter than what I have here?

Tags: sql

I was just wondering, how I can just make this code shorter?

```
SELECT 
    MAX(ISNULL(BatchNumber, 0)) + 1 
FROM 
    (SELECT BatchNumber 
     FROM ExportBatch 
     UNION 
     SELECT 0)
```

Comment: Is there a benefit of this SQL query being "shorter"?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it could be shorter:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM ExportBatch;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0ce173c6b8cda8351d70e990b5c8b806)**

But I would suggest using [SEQUENCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) or IDENTITY instead.

Comment: This is relying on there being a completely gapless sequence, ie no rows ever deleted, no rolled back transactions that incremented the sequence. Counting all the rows will also be slower than getting the max of an indexed column.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you use the subquery just in case the table is empty.
But you don't need to, because with aggregate function `MAX()` in your query, you will always get a row in the results:

```
SELECT ISNULL(MAX(BatchNumber), 0) + 1 
FROM ExportBatch
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(BatchNumber + 1, 1))
FROM ExportBatch ;
```

However, you should be using an auto-incrementing column for `BatchNumber`.  You should not be assigning it manually -- `identity`, `autoincrement` or `generated always as identity` are typical syntax for such a column.